# Unable to update data in firebase database while using phone authentication in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, firebase-authentication, registration

I am trying to add user registering form data to firebase database. But have tough time doing it effectivily. I am new to the flutter. I successfully register the user via phone number but unable to add corresponding details. I tried using getter and setter but it obviously is not working. I don't know what is idealic method of doing that. I tried googling it but didn't got any help. I am just stuck. I will really appreciate it.

Here is my code

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:home_crisp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:home_crisp/services/auth.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';


class ChefRegisterScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  ChefRegisterScreen();

  @override
  _ChefRegisterScreenState createState() => _ChefRegisterScreenState();
}

class _ChefRegisterScreenState extends State<ChefRegisterScreen> {
  final AuthService _auth = AuthService();

  bool loading = false;
  final GlobalKey<FormState> _formKey = GlobalKey<FormState>();

  String chefName = "", phoneNo = "";
  String smsCode, verificationID;
  String phnCode = "+92";
  DateTime dateOfBirth;
  bool codeSent = false;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final user = Provider.of<User>(context);
    final deviceSize = MediaQuery.of(context).size;
    return loading
        ? Loading()
        : Material(
            type: MaterialType.card,
            color: Color(0xffD4EBD3),
            child: Stack(
              children: <Widget>[

            // --> Here is the code of getting "chefname, phone and dateOfBirth" and setting them using setState() method 

                              //
                              // >>>>>>>>> Textfeild for getting OTP code 
                              //

                              codeSent
                                  ? // Here is the code for textfeild which get OTP code
                                  : Container(),

// ------------------------------------------------------   F I N I S H    B U T T O N

                              FlatButton(
                                onPressed: () async {



                                    if (user != null) {
                                      print(
                                          "TheRe IS  uSer already logging in so signing out logging in new user");
                                      AuthService().signOut();
                                    }

                                    if (codeSent) {
                                      AuthService().signInWithOTP(smsCode, verificationID);
                                    } else {
                                      verifyPhone(phoneNo);
                                    }

// ----> Here I tried to several methods to sent register form data to the seperate class named 
// ----> "user.dart" from where I tried to extract that info in "auth" signinWithPhoneNumber method.
// ----> I first tried to send the info via constructor

                                  ChefData(chefName: chefName,
                                          chefPhNo: phoneNo,
                                          chefDateOfBirth: dateOfBirth);
                                    }); 
// ----> Then I tried "setter" but in vain
                                    // ChefData().setChefName(chefName);
                                    // ChefData().setChefPhNo(phoneNo);
                                    // ChefData().setChefDateOfBirth(dateOfBirth);

                                child: ClipRRect(
                                  child: Text(
                                        "FINISH",
                                        style: TextStyle(
                                          color: Colors.white,
                                          fontFamily: 'Montserrat',
                                          fontSize: 20,
                                        ),
                                      ),
                                ),
                              ),



                            ],
                          ),
                        ),
                      )
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          );
  }

  //
  // >>>>>>>>> S I G N   I N   W I T H   P H O M E  N U M B E R   P R O C E S S
  //
  Future<void> verifyPhone(phoneNo) async {
    final PhoneVerificationCompleted verificationComplete =
        (AuthCredential authResult) {
      print('1. Auto retrieving verification code');

      }
    };

    final PhoneCodeAutoRetrievalTimeout autoRetrieve = (String verID) {
      verificationID = verID;
      print("\n2. Auto retrieval time out");
    };

    final PhoneCodeSent smsCodeSent =
        (String verID, [int forceCodeResend]) async {
      verificationID = verID;
      setState(() {
        this.codeSent = true;
      });
      print("\n 3. Code Sent to " + phoneNo);
    };

    final PhoneVerificationFailed verificationFailed =
        (AuthException authException) {
      print('${AuthException(smsCode, "message")}');
      if (authException.message.contains('not authorized'))
        print('App not authroized');
      else if (authException.message.contains('Network'))
        print('Please check your internet connection and try again');
      else
        print('Something has gone wrong, please try later ' +
            authException.message);
    };

    await FirebaseAuth.instance
        .verifyPhoneNumber(
          phoneNumber: phoneNo,
          timeout: Duration(seconds: 50),
          verificationCompleted: verificationComplete,
          verificationFailed: verificationFailed,
          codeSent: smsCodeSent,
          codeAutoRetrievalTimeout: autoRetrieve,
        )
        .then((value) {})
        .catchError((error) {
      print(error.toString());
    });
  }
}
```

Here is the "auth.dart" class

```
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:home_crisp/models/user.dart';
import 'package:home_crisp/services/database.dart';

class AuthService {
  final FirebaseAuth _auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // create user obj based on FirebaseUser

  User _userFormFirebaseUser(FirebaseUser user) {
    return user != null ? User(uid: user.uid) : null;
  }

  // auth change user stream
  Stream<User> get user {
    return _auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(_userFormFirebaseUser);
  }

  // ------------------------------------------------------ S I G N   I N   W I T H   P H O M E  N U M B E R

  signInWithPhoneNumber(AuthCredential authCreds) async {
    try {
      AuthResult result = await _auth.signInWithCredential(authCreds);
      FirebaseUser user = result.user;

      if (user != null) {
        print('AUTHENTICATONI SUCCESSFULL. Id: ' + user.uid);

// ---->> Now here I tried create a new document for the chef with the uid by extracting the chef data // // ---->> from "user.dart" class 

// ---->> I used getter method. I know there is going to be some better way to get that data

await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateChefData(
            ChefData().getChefName(),
            ChefData().getChefPhNo(),
            ChefData().getChefDateOfBirth());

        return _userFormFirebaseUser(user);
      } else {
        print('Invalid code/invalid authentication');
      }
    } catch (e) {
      print(e.toString());
      return null;
    }
  }

  signInWithOTP(smsCode, verId) {
    AuthCredential authCreds = PhoneAuthProvider.getCredential(
        verificationId: verId, smsCode: smsCode);
    signInWithPhoneNumber(authCreds);
  }
}
```

Here is "user.dart" file containing "ChefData" class acting as intermediary between "auth.dart" and "chefRegisterScreen.dart"

```
class User {

final String uid;
  User({this.uid});
}


class ChefData {
  String chefId;
  String chefName;
  String chefPhNo;
  DateTime chefDateOfBirth;

  ChefData({this.chefId, this.chefName, this.chefPhNo, this.chefDateOfBirth});

  // void setChefId(String _chefId) {
  //   this.chefId = _chefId;
  // }

  // void setChefName(String _chefName) {
  //   this.chefName = _chefName;
  // }

  // void setChefPhNo(String _chefPhNo) {
  //   this.chefPhNo = chefPhNo;
  // }

  // DateTime setChefDateOfBirth(DateTime _chefDateOfBirth) {
  //   this.chefDateOfBirth = _chefDateOfBirth;
  // }

  String getChefId() {
    return chefId;
  }

  String getChefName() {
    return chefName;
  }

  String getChefPhNo() {
    return chefPhNo;
  }

  DateTime getChefDateOfBirth() {
    return chefDateOfBirth;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem and I used shared preferences to store the user details during registration then uploaded the details after phone authentication was successful.
Shared preferences is a flutter plugin that allows you to store simple data in key-value pair form.[Here](https://medium.com/flutterdevs/using-sharedpreferences-in-flutter-251755f07127) is a more detailed article about shared preferences and how to use it.

In your case, I suggest you create a class for shared preferences.

```
class SharedPreference{
  static Future<String> storeChefData(ChefData chefData) async {
  SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
  String storeUser = userToJson(chefData);
  await prefs.setString('user', storeUser);
  return storeUser;
 }

 static Future<ChefData> getChefData() async {
   SharedPreferences prefs = await SharedPreferences.getInstance();
   if (prefs.getString('user') != null) {
     ChefData chefData = userFromJson(prefs.getString('user'));
  return chefData;
  } else {
    return null;
   }
  }
 }
```

The `storeChefData()` function is for storing users details during registration. While the `getChefData()` function is for retrieving the users details in order to upload to the database after authentication.

In your user.dart file you will be required to add functions that convert the chefData to jsonData for storage and from jsonData to ChefData for retrieval as shown in the above functions.

```
ChefData userFromJson(String str) {
  final jsonData = json.decode(str);
  return ChefData.fromJson(jsonData);
}

String userToJson(ChefData data) {
  final dyn = data.toJson();
  return json.encode(dyn);
}

class ChefData{
  final String chefName;
  final String chefPhNo;
  final DateTime chefDateOfBirth;

  ChefData({this.chefName,this.chefPhNo,this.chefDateOfBirth});

  factory ChefData.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) => ChefData(
    chefName: json["chefName"],
    chefPhNo: json["chefPhNo"]
    chefDateOfBirth: json["chefDateOfBirth"]
  );

  Map<String, dynamic> toJson() => {
     "chefName": chefName,
     "chefPhNo": chefPhNo
     "chefDateOfBirth": chefDateOfBirth
  };
}
```

In your `ChefRegistrationScreen` you will add:

```
await SharedPreference.storeChefData(ChefData(chefName: chefName,chefPhNo: phoneNo,chefDateOfBirth: dateOfBirth));
```

at the point where you would like to insert the chefData.

Then in your `auth.dart` file you will add:

```
ChefData getChefData = await SharedPreference.getChefData();
await DatabaseService(uid: user.uid).updateUserData(getChefData);
```

in order to update your database.